# file input/output in Vala (IOChannel vs FileStream vs IOStream)

Tags: glib, vala

I have a few fds (obtained from `Process.spawn_async_with_pipes`) that I want to read from and write to. Now I saw that there are multiple ways to do so:

- using `IOChannel.unix_new`
- using `FileStream.fdopen`
- using `UnixInputStream` and `UnixOutputStream`

What is the difference between these APIs and which one should I take?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846511/read-write-file-pipes-in-vala-glib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IOChannel

- [Part of GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html)
- Portable support for using files, pipes and sockets

FileStream

- Not part of GLib / GIO
- Binds to standard C library (libc) fopen, fclose, fwrite, etc.

UnixInputStream / UnixOutputStream

- [Part of GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GUnixInputStream.html) (gio-unix to be precise, it's Unix only as far as I know)
- Supports the InputStream and OutputStream interfaces
- Good for abstraction of different types of streams
- There are also Win32InputStream and Win32OutputStream for dealing with Windows file handles in GIO

So it depends on several factors which one to use:

- Do you need non Unix support?
- Do you want to use the GIO abstract interfaces?
- Do you need to work with FILE*
- Do you need to work with Windows file handles